# Kubevirt virtctl image-upload gives "remote error: tls: bad certificate error"

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to upload windows10 image to pvc inorder to create a windows10 vm using **kubevirt**.
I used below **virtctl** command:

`$ virtctl image-upload --image-path=/Win10_20H2_v2_English_x64.iso --pvc-name=win10-vm --access-mode=ReadWriteMany --pvc-size=5G --uploadproxy-url=https://<cdi-uploadproxy IP>:443 --insecure`

**Result :**

- pvc is created

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                     STATUS   VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
win10-vm                 Bound    pv0002   10Gi       RWX                           145m
win10-vm-scratch         Bound    pv0003   10Gi       RWX                           145m
```

- cdi-image-upload pod is created.

```
[root@master kubevirt]# kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
cdi                    cdi-apiserver-847d4bc7dc-l6fz7               1/1     Running   1          135m
cdi                    cdi-deployment-66d7555b79-d57bm              1/1     Running   1          135m
cdi                    cdi-operator-895bb5c74-hpk44                 1/1     Running   1          135m
cdi                    cdi-uploadproxy-6c8698cd8b-z67xc             1/1     Running   1          134m
default                cdi-upload-win10-vm                          1/1     Running   0          53s
```

But upload gets timeout.When I checked logs of the **cdi-upload-win10-vm**  pod,I got following errors:

```
I0413 10:58:38.695097       1 uploadserver.go:70] Upload destination: /data/disk.img
I0413 10:58:38.695263       1 uploadserver.go:72] Running server on 0.0.0.0:8443
2021/04/13 10:58:40 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:57710: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2021/04/13 10:58:45 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:57770: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2021/04/13 10:58:50 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:57882: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2021/04/13 10:58:55 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:57940: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2021/04/13 10:59:00 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:58008: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2021/04/13 10:59:05 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:58066: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2021/04/13 10:59:10 http: TLS handshake error from [::1]:58136: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

Comment: Get you end up solving this?

Comment: Raised an issue in the git repo for this at https://github.com/kubevirt/kubevirt/issues/5473